# Bash - Passing an array to remote hosts via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, array

I wrote a Bash script that logs in to multiple remote hosts and runs `smartctl` (from the `smartmontools` package) on disks defined in the array `DISKS`. I'm able to pass the array to the remote hosts, but the script just echos the first element over and over. It seems like it's treating the array as a string, and ignoring all elements after the first.

```
DISKS=("/dev/sda" "/dev/sdb" "/dev/sdc")
HOSTS=("Ariadne" "Nyx")

for i in "${HOSTS[@]}"; do
    ssh "$i" "bash" << EOF
        for j in "${DISKS[@]}"; do
            echo "$j"
        done
EOF
done
```

I've tried defining the array on the remote host (before the 2nd for loop): `DISKS=("${DISKS[@]}")`, but that did not help.

How can I properly pass an array to a remote host via SSH, and then iterate through the array?

Comment: There is a `do` missing in your remote `for` loop.

Comment: The `do` in the 2nd `for` loop is present in the actual script. I would get a `syntax error` if it wasn't.  I must have missed it when I copied and pasted. I have added it to the script above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the definition of the array to the remote `bash` like so (here assuming the login shell of the remote user is `bash`):

```
DISKS_definition=$(typeset -p DISKS)
for i in "${HOSTS[@]}"; do
  ssh "$i" "$DISKS_definition"'
    for j in "${DISKS[@]}"; do
      echo "$j"
    done'
done
```

Or if using the here-document approach:

```
DISKS_definition=$(typeset -p DISKS)
for i in "${HOSTS[@]}"; do
  ssh "$i" bash <<EOF
    $DISKS_definition
    for j in "\${DISKS[@]}"; do
      echo "\$j"
    done
EOF
done
```

If your `ssh` client and server allow passing `LC_*` variables, you could also do

```
DISKS_definition=$(typeset -p DISKS)
for i in "${HOSTS[@]}"; do
  LC_DISKS=$DISKS_definition ssh "$i" bash <<'EOF'
    eval "$LC_DISKS"
    for j in "${DISKS[@]}"; do
      echo "$j"
    done
EOF
done
```

All is in the quoting that determines which of the local or remote shell does the expansions. Remember variables are expanded inside double quotes and here-documents where the delimiter is not quoted (note the `<<'EOF'` in the last example that prevents expansions inside the here-document while in the earlier examples (with `<<EOF`) we had to use backslashes for things that we don't want expanded by the local shell).

For arrays that contain non-ASCII data, you'll want to make sure that the locale's character set is the same on the local and remote machine, or at least avoid multi-byte character sets other than UTF-8.

```
bash-4.3$ locale charmap
ISO-8859-1
bash-4.3$ a=($'foo\xa3$(uname>&2)bar' baz)
bash-4.3$ a_definition=$(typeset -p a)
bash-4.3$ LC_ALL=zh_HK.big5hkscs bash -c "$a_definition"
Linux
```

By switching to a different character set, the content of `$a_definition` took a different meaning (here causing the `uname>&2` command to be executed).

Comment: I haven't tried the other methods, but the here-doc approach works wonderfully, and it is consistent with the structure of my script, so I only have to make a few changes. I was previously using `LC_*` variables to pass the variables across, but then I discovered it wasn't necessary, the vars are being passed without an issue. It was then that I realized the array wasn't being passed.

The key line is `DISKS_definition=$(typeset -p DISKS)`, that was all I needed to get it working (as well as escaping the `$`'s.)

Comment: @AndyForceno, note that passing the variables as `ssh host "echo $variable"` is dangerous and in the general case bad practice as the variable is expanded as _code_ for the remote shell. For instance if `$variable` is `foo;reboot`, that causes the `reboot` command to be executed on the remote host. When using `$(typeset -p)`, the shell quotes the text as needed to prevent this kind of thing from happening (as long as the charset is the same as discussed).

Comment: When I try to pass `LC_DISKS=$DISKS_definition`, I get the error: `bash: -a: command not found`.

Comment: @AndyForceno Sorry.  Typo. Not sure why you would get that error message though.

Comment: I figured out the problem, and it was my mistake. I noticed that I had defined `LC_DISKS` after calling `ssh`, but in your script (with the quoted here-document, 3rd example above) it's the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Your `echo "$j"` is evaluated when the `ssh` command line is evaluated, so inside the `for j...` for loop it's actually a constant (and undefined, at that) rather than a variable.

Try this

```
for i in "${HOSTS[@]}"; do
    ssh "$i" "bash" << EOF
        for j in "${DISKS[@]}"; do
            echo "\$j"
        done
EOF
done
```

Or this, if your `$DISKS` array contains safe words without whitespace.

```
for i in "${HOSTS[@]}"; do
    ssh "$i" "for j in ${DISKS[@]}; do echo \"\$j\"; done"
done
```

---

My preferred way of solving this kind of problem is to create a script that performs the necessary work and have that reside on each remote server. Calling the script on each server then becomes a straightforward and simple process:

```
for h in "${HOSTS[@]}"; do ssh "$h" /usr/local/bin/myscript; done
```

If you're worried about the script becoming out of date, it's not an impossible task to copy the file across from the local system before running it. Something like this would probably work:

```
for h in "${HOSTS[@]}"
do
    scp -p /local/path/to/myscript "$h":myscript.$$
    ssh "$h" "myscript.$$; rm -f myscript.$$"
done
```

Comment: The first one outputs the entire array at once, rather than iterating through the elements. The second one works, but it is problematic if you have more code after the 2nd for loop. I have more lines of code that I omitted from the question since they are not relevant. I can certainly add them to the ssh line, but it's going to be messy!

Comment: @AndyForceno I've offered a different way of solving the problem

Comment: In the first example `${DISKS[@]}` is expanded by the local shells, so _unsafe_ words would also be a problem (like `DISKS=('$(reboot)')`) and you don't want the quotes around it.